# Run a python script @reboot using crontab

Tags: linux, cron, raspberry-pi3, job-scheduling

I wan to run a python script every time my computer boots up. For this I have seen quiet some tutorials that suggest to do

```
  crontab -e      
  @reboot python3 /home/user/Desktop/my_script.py
```

It would be nice if I can also start is after lets say 30 seconds, so I do

```
 @reboot sleep 30; python3 /home/user/Desktop/my_script.py
```

I have tried it on my computer as well as on a Raspberry Pi, but it doesn't seem to work. To check I make the python script make a graph and save it on desktop, but it doesn't do so. However , it runs fine if I run it manually from terminal. Can someone help what I am missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `/etc/rc.local` file ?

Add the command inside the file with full path (example: `/usr/bin/python ...`) and mark the file executable.

`chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

Note: Make sure to use full path to the executables, else export `PATH` variable in the `/etc/rc.local` file.

Comment: Hi...I also tried your method, but I don't see a graph getting saved anywhere.

Comment: something is wrong with the script. can you debug the execution of the script ? try debug execution with piping the output to another file, something like `cmd &>> tempfile`